# Strange behavior of .capitalize function

Tags: python

I've matched strange behavior of ***.capitalize*** function with ***reduce***.

```
from functools import reduce
def camel_case(string):
    return reduce(lambda x,y:x.capitalize()+y.capitalize(),string.split())
```

and the result of `camel_case('camel case word')` is `'CamelcaseWord'` while when I use `.upper()`,for example,everything works fine.

What I misunderstand?
Thanks everyone for response!

Comment: What is your expected output?

Comment: Rather than `reduce`, you can `str.title().replace(" ", "")` to do this.

Comment: And if you really have to use `reduce`, the correct way to do this is to use an empty string as the initialiser argument: `reduce((lambda a, b: a + b.capitalize()), iterable, "")`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

since you use the `reduce` function, when you call camel_case with 'camel case word' it is equivalent to the following code:

```
x,y,z = s.split()
(x.capitalize() + y.capitalize()).capitalize() + z.capitalize()
```

Now, the 3rd capitalize (from left) will turn all characters to lower case and the first character will become upper case so you get

```
(x.capitalize() + y.capitalize()).capitalize()
```

equals to 'Camelcase' and,

```
z.capitalize()
```

equals to 'Word'. Hence the result.

Now, when you use upper, calling `(x.upper() + y.upper()).upper()` is equivalent to  `x.upper() + y.upper()` so you won't notice the difference.